# replace xml root tag with attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, tags, root

Need XSLT code to convert XML root tag with attribute value:
My input XML is like as below:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="false"?>
<Message IntObjectFormat="SH" MessageType="IO" IntObjectName="IO"     MessageId="1" MsgType="CreateService">
<CreateServiceProvider>
<ServiceProvider>
<Id>11</Id>
<AccountGroup>FMLY</AccountGroup>
<Name>rin</Name>
<Status>Active</Status>
<ParentId/>
<MainPhoneNumber>041</MainPhoneNumber>
<MainFaxNumber/>
<MainEmailAddress/>
<ABNCode/>
<PrimaryAddressStreetNo>2</PrimaryAddressStreetNo>
<PrimaryAddressStreetName>Marl</PrimaryAddressStreetName>
<StreetSuffix>Pl</StreetSuffix>
<Postcode>2558</Postcode>
<AddressCountry>Austria/AddressCountry>
</ServiceProvider>
</CreateServiceProvider>
</Message>
```

I need output as below where my Root tag name "Message" get converted into the value which I am getting in "MsgType" attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="false"?>
<CreateService IntObjectFormat="SH" MessageType="IO" IntObjectName="IO"    MessageId="1" MsgType="CreateService">
<CreateServiceProvider>
<ServiceProvider>
<Id>11</Id>
<AccountGroup>FMLY</AccountGroup>
<Name>rin</Name>
<Status>Active</Status>
<ParentId/>
<MainPhoneNumber>041</MainPhoneNumber>
<MainFaxNumber/>
<MainEmailAddress/>
<ABNCode/>
<PrimaryAddressStreetNo>2</PrimaryAddressStreetNo>
<PrimaryAddressStreetName>Marl</PrimaryAddressStreetName>
<StreetSuffix>Pl</StreetSuffix>
<Postcode>2558</Postcode>
<AddressCountry>Austria/AddressCountry>
</ServiceProvider>
</CreateServiceProvider>
</CreateService>
```

Thanks.

Regards,
AJ

Comment: "*Need XSLT code*" is not a question.

Comment: would you consider writing a simple app instead of xslt? if so I will do a submission